# PHP: Use function outside current function

Tags: php

can I use a function that is outside the current function?

eg.

```
function one($test){
return 1;
}
function two($id){
one($id);
}
```

Seems like i cant, how should I do it then to use the function that are outside? Thanks

The function is in the same file.. /

Comment: If one couldn't do that, then functions could only call themselves which is a pretty limited use of functions. So, yes, of course you can do it like that and the code above is perfectly valid. Why do you think it does not work? Just calling `two(5)` would not produce any output, so you cannot know whether it "worked" or not. In any case, have a look at: http://php.net/manual/en/language.functions.php

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is your function inside of a class? In that case you have to use `$this->function()` instead of `function()`.

Answer (score 4):

That's perfectly valid. Check out [the running code here](http://codepad.org/SgBcXSxJ).

Answer (score 3):

Your code looks valid to me : you are declaring two functions, called `one` and `two` ; and `two` is calling `one`.

Then, you can call any of those functions, to execute it.

For example, if you execute the following portion of code :

```
function one($test){
    var_dump(__FUNCTION__);
    return 1;
}
function two($id){
    var_dump(__FUNCTION__);
    one($id);
}

two('plop');
```

*Note that I called `two`, in the last line of this example.*

You'll get this kind of output :

```
string 'two' (length=3)

string 'one' (length=3)
```

Which shows that both functions were executed.

Answer (score 1):

That works fine.  However, `one` ignores its parameter.  Then, `two` ignores the return value from `one`.

Answer (score 0):

This should work fine
Example:

```
<?php
function test ($asd)
{
    return $asd;
}
function run ()
{
    return test('dd');
}

echo run();
?>
```

Maybe you have an issue elsewhere?